# How to pin mouse on page inactive (js | jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent

Is there any way to pin mouse at death line boder of the page if it leave out this page? and unpin if mouse entered
in code it would probably look similar to the following:

```
$('html').mouseleave(function(e) {
var pageX = e.pageX || e.clientX,
    pageY = e.pageY || e.clientY
   if (page X < 0 || pageY < 0) { //
    //do something to pin mouse 
   }
}).mouseenter(function() {
  // do something to unpin mouse
});
```

Comment: What did you mean by pinning?

Comment: look like simulator a mouse and keep it alway on the page, at last position mouse leave out the page.